# "Play Music" app keeps changing the volume of the sound by itself

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, volume-control

I bought a new Galaxy S4 a few days ago and since then I have been facing problems with the "Play Music" app. It keeps changing the sound volume while a song is playing. I tried applying different settings in the player but the problem still persists. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the "Google Play Music" app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android automatically corrects my volume](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123150/android-automatically-corrects-my-volume)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the original earphone. The original earphone has volume control on it, if you use different earphone you can get this problem.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention this only happens when they're using headphones, or even that they are even using headphones at all. Also phones (should) work with any brand of headphone, not just manufacturer provided ones.