# Android automatically corrects my volume

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, volume-control, volume

I have a bit annoying problem. My Android 4.2 Jelly Bean automatically corrects volume down every few minutes. It is rather annoying than a problem.

I tried to find and switch off this functionality, but i was not successful.

Can somebody help me where i can find it and switch it off?

Tablet is not rooted.
This occure when I listen Google Play, when I am not listening to music, when i have switched on or off Google Play. 
It happenes about every 10 minutes or something like that.
It happens when plugged headphones via connector or without it. Bluetooth not tested.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it happening if you connect a headset or connect via bluetooth devices etc? Or when the phone is idle and Do you use different music player than Google's Play Music app. Please add when exactly and how frequently does it occur. And also mention your phone model and whether is it rooted?

Comment: [Seems like a specific issue with Play Music](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50426/play-music-app-keeps-changing-the-volume-of-the-sound-by-itself) (no solution yet)

Comment: Updated status: After turning this android device back to stock setting and  installing Google Play again this bug didn't show off yet again.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible reasons to why the problem occurs;**

**Power saving feature (both inherent or acquired from third-party applications.**

Some users suggest that this can be attributed to a power saving feature in the ROM.

> As soon as it hits 30% battery and that activates, it changes all my volume settings. [Volume settings auto-adjust themselves?](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-mini/335205-volume-settings-auto-adjust-themselves.html)

This suspected feature is also thought to be provided by applications such as AVG optimisation feature etc

**Incompatibility issues with headphones with in-built mic**

It was observed that when doing an action that generates sound (i.e driving, running etc), the mic input in the head phones, this extra sound is somewhere compensated by a *reduction in device volume*.

Another possible theory to explain this scenario was described by one user:

> When using headphones that does not have built-in controls the phone misinterprets small variations in voltage as commands to adjust volume. These variations are likely caused by phone’s own power saving, peaks in audio being played etc. Such small variations in voltage via the grounding pin are being interpreted by the phone as “volume down commands”. `

**Bugs in Android versions**

This problem has been noted by many users as a major bug in lollipop and I think earlier versions could have been vitims too. Not only is the Galaxy S4 model affected by this bug, infact other device models e.g LG, Galaxy S3 etc running  lollipop version seems to be affected as well.

---

**Possible fixes**

1. **Using Volume locking applications**

   Various applications such as  [Volume Lock & Mute](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.dieterthiess.stfu&hl=en) were shown to be a working solution:

An alternative application [Volume Control-Volume Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myunglab.VolumeControl&hl=en) has been shown to do the job

2. **Replacing headphones**

Following this evidence:

> I found the problem finally. I found that if I use headphones that have a mic built in, it was the cause of the problem. Luckily my headphones came with a lead that could be unplugged from the headphones so I bought a new jack lead with no inbuilt mic and ii fixed the problem.

Another user was affirmative with this workaround:

> Long story short, try not to use headphones with an inbuilt mic/volume control esp. while exercising (I find this is often the time this occurs).

3. **Observing the device in Safe Mode**

Try booting your device in Safe Mode. If the problem stops, there is definitely a third-party app triggering it.

However, if the problem is still there, it might be the Android software itself triggering the issue or a hardware-related fault. Simply delete the app that you suspect has compatibility issues with your music player.

4. **Performing a Factory Reset**

When the above solutions do not work, go to Recovery Mode and select Factory Reset. This will totally restore your phone to its factory settings. It will completely wipe all your stored files though, so remember to backup your data prior to this. You also wipe the cache partition in Recovery Mode if even Factory Reset fails.

5. **Upgrading OS version**

If the problem is due to an OS version update, wait for another OTA update that contains a fix from your unit’s carrier or manufacturer. When there are no updates or updates fail to fix the issue, you can root and flash your phone, then, install a custom ROM that will remove the issue. This is very risky though, so do your research about the process first or seek help from a technician.

**Other workarounds**

Another workaround is using [automation](/questions/tagged/automation). You can try using [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net) ($2.99 but available as a trial version for 7 fays)
Basically here, you want to set the media volume at constant level preferably when playing music or other media:

- We need to create a Profile that can be linked to a certain Task say (Volume lock) when the conditions are met (variable is set to media volume, music app is opened)

Here is a workaround using Tasker:

**Task**

Go to the Task tab

- Select "New Task + "
- You can name this Task *KeepSameVol* or anything.
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Audio >> Media Volume  [Level :10 (or any value) Dislay (optional just a pop up alert)
- Tap back to exit from this task
- Press back all the way to exit (Your task is saved)

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows setting of predeterminded media volume level:

- Goto Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event >> Variable set >> %VOLM
- Long press the "+" to add another option
- State >> Variable value >> %VOLM != 10 (media volume isn't equal to 10)
- Long press the "+" to add another option
- Application >> Select your Music/Media applications
- Tap back to exit from this window

[image]

**Link the Task to the profile**

*Explanation: When an media application is opened,acheck is made if the volume is set to a defined level (i.e 10 in this case), if not 
equal to ths value then a Taskis processed to adjust the volume to that level and make sure its constant*

Hope this helps

**References**

1. [Volume decreases when playing audio with headphones](https://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m9/553831-volume-decreases-when-playing-audio-headphones.html)
2. [Samsung Galaxy S3 Volume going crazy](https://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii/281623-samsung-galaxy-s3-volume-going-crazy.html)
3. [Why does ringer volume keep going down?](https://androidforums.com/threads/why-does-ringer-volume-keep-going-down.919512/)
4. [Samsung Galaxy S4 Music Volume Goes Down on Its Own](http://thedroidguy.com/2014/04/samsung-galaxy-s4-music-volume-goes-89032)
5. [Possible to lock volume to certain level, so volume buttons don't do anything?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4st3ue/possible_to_lock_volume_to_certain_level_so/)
6. [S7 Edge, Volume lock?](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/666152-s7-edge-volume-lock.html)

Answer (score 2):

Revised [earlier solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/177885/3) , optimizing it and reducing it to a single macro - keep it *simple* (instead of two). This works fine - shouldn't take you more than 20 minutes to set up for test (even if you haven't ever used this app )

---

My solution is towards providing a *simple , tested* fix to the problem using [automation](/questions/tagged/automation)

I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn.  Install the app , grant it permissions requested and you are good to go.

**Logic**

- User decides a predetermined volume level that is comfortable
- Launches Google Play music and keeps it in **foreground**
- Play music - Every 3 seconds the macro forces the volume level to the predetermined volume level , thus ensuring fading of music or tuning out doesn't happen. 3 seconds is  arbitrarily chosen with the assumption that volume changes in 3 seconds will not be detected by ear - decrease it as you wish , if volume changes are jarring. I tested down to 800 milli seconds
- To stop this volume adjustment (exit condition ), either switch the app to background or minimize it. Macro stops working

**Testing Done**

Since I don't have this problem with Google Play Music on my Moto X Play, I tested by by pressing <kbd>Vol up</kbd> and <kbd>Vol down</kbd> keys ( to simulate changes in volume ) but the player volume remained at predetermined level. I have tested it extensively , since my earlier solution

---

You need a single Macro for this - it looks to be a  tad lengthy process  only because all the steps have been described in detail ( 20 minute promise holds )

Your macro would look like this

[image]

(Triggers / Actions / Constraints are added by **`+`**   on the right side of each panel )

### Macro : Lossless Music ( named by me - name it whatever )

This macro does *fixing the predetermined level, polling every 3 seconds and ensuring that volume stays there*

**Triggers** :

**Triggers** : *Application Launched / Closed* → *Application Launched* → `OK` → *Select Google Play Music* and `OK`

( When Google Play Music is launched , actions  below happen )

**Actions**:

- *Repeat Actions* ( second item on drop down when you press the plus sign on action panel )→ *While condition repeat* → *Conditions **`+`*** → *Application Running* → *Running in Foreground* →`OK` → *Google Play Music* and `OK`

This creates a while / do loop wherein we want something to be done when Google Play Music is in foreground. You see now a WHILE / DO - End Loop created . Tap the *End Loop* and you will get a pop up *Add action above*. Tap that and add actions below

- *Volume Change* → select *Media / Music* and set slider to say 75 % tap `OK` (this is the **predetermined level** and can be varied as you like )
- *Wait before next action* → set it to 3 seconds ( or less as you want )

**Constraints** : Leave blank

**Save** and you are done !

---

**Improvements possible**

- If you are the kind that prefers to play Google Play Music in background and wish to modify the macro , it's simple - replace *foreground* with *background* in above macro
- If you want to have this behavior whether Play Music is in foreground OR background, it is also possible but you would need two macros for it - I have configured them and will add if you want

Comment: For anyone interested in the macro to work in both background and foreground see [solution here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179105/131553)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (Tested with OnePlus 5): The **Equalizer**.

Turn off the equalizer in **System Settings**, or at least the "Limiter".

To balance music volumes and reduce sudden bursts, the equalizer automatically raises volume on quieter parts of a music and turns down volume at bursts. This causes troubles frequently so I don't like it.

P.S. Someone told me to turn off equalizer in GPM but I can't find such a setting so I'm not adding it here.

References:

1. AndroidCentral – [Google play music volume issues](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/297718-google-play-music-volume-issues.html)
2. Galaxy S4 Forums – [Google Music volume increases and decreases on its own](http://www.galaxys4forums.net/forum/15-galaxy-s4-audio/2016-google-music-volume-increases-decreases-its-own.html)